# how to use full amount in division

Tags: fair-division

How to use the full amount in a division?
So if I want to divide `10 / 3`, I want the following results `[ 3.33, 3.33, 3.34 ]` (if going for 2 decimal places), or `[ 3.333, 3.333, 3.334 ]` (if going for 3 decimal places)

Comment: I'm not following. So you're distributing an amount to different cells? So that $1/3 + 1/3 + 1/3 = 1$? And what do you mean by "use the full amount"?

Comment: A calculator gives you $\frac{10}{3} = 3.333 \dots$, what's the problem with that?

Comment: If I want to divide 10 dollars between 3 people I have to give `3.33` to one person, `3.33` to another and `3.34` to the last, I cannot give `10/3` to each.

Comment: @MattiP. If 3.3333333.... is rounded to two decimal places, you get 3.33. However, if you add the rounded values 3.33+3.33+3.33 you get 9.99 and not 10. He is looking for some routine which makes up for the missing 0.01 and adds it to one of the rounded values.

Comment: What rule do you seek to follow?  Say, for instance, we are dividing $17$ by $7$.  That's $2.4285714$.  If you want to do it to two places, you'd give everyone $2.42$ to start...but then $7\times 2.42=16.94$.  So...we could assign the missing $.06$ to one person, or give $.01$ to six people (among other options).  Which do you do and why?

Comment: @lulu the fairest: give .01 to six people

Comment: Ok, so do that.  First truncate, then compute the difference and apportion it.  Is there an instance where that goes wrong?